# How to remove an element from a list in Python when element is contained in a variable

Tags: python, list

I am new to programming and have just completed my first term coursework for UNI. When dealing with the last details of my coursework I came across a challenge to which I did not find an answer to on stack overflow yet.

I have a list called cL (coloursList), and am trying to remove one element from this list, element which is contained within a variable called "colour2", which is inputted by the user through the shell using the "input" method.

I have found methods of removing elements from a list by using list.remove(x) or list.pop(x) by referring to the element itself (by providing the element's name as a string), or the element's index position within the list.

This is how the bit of code that I'm working with looks like:

```
    # more code before this

    cL = ["red", "green", "blue", "magenta", "orange", "pink"]

    elif colour2 == colour1:
        cL = cL.remove(colour2)
        print("\nPlease select a different colour than previous one:\n", cL) 
        colour2 = str(input("Please re-enter second colour: "))

    # more code to follow
```

Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is that when the user inputs the 2nd or 3rd colour he is being prompted for in the shell, if he inputs a colour he has previously used from the list, I am trying to remove that colour from the list, then present the new amended list to the user, so he knows which colours he has left to choose from.

Obviously this bit of code I tried doesn't work

```
cL = cL.remove(colour2)
```

And am trying to see what options are there in achieving this task.

Thank you very much!

******* UPDATE CONTAINING COMPLETE CODE (FOR CURIOUS PEOPLE) *******

******* Task completed with help of STACK OVERFLOW community *******

```
    cL = ["red", "green", "blue", "magenta", "orange", "pink"]

print("\nAvailable colours to choose from:\n", cL)
colour1 = str(input("Please enter FIRST colour: ")).lower()
while True:
    if colour1 not in cL:
        print("\nInvalid colour.\nPlease choose a colour from list:\n", cL)
        colour1 = str(input("Please re-enter a valid FIRST colour: "))\
                      .lower()
    else:
        cL.remove(colour1)
        break

print("\nGREAT WORK! Remaining valid colours to choose from are:\n", cL)        
colour2 = str(input("Please enter SECOND colour: ")).lower()
while True:
    if colour2 not in cL:
        print("\nInvalid colour.\nPlease choose a colour from list:\n", cL)
        colour2 = str(input("Please re-enter a valid SECOND colour: "))\
                      .lower()
    else:
        cL.remove(colour2)
        break
```

This is how my completed colour input validation code looks like (for first and second colour). Thought it might help someone who has a similar task to complete in the future.

*Colour input can be [lower case], [UPPER CASE] or [A MiX oF bOtH], and unless the user chooses one of the colours presented to him before choosing any of the colours, he'll be stuck in a loop asking him to choose a valid colour from the list provided.

Comment: `cL = cL.remove(colour2)` looks fishy. I'm pretty sure remove doesn't return the list.

Comment: So cL is list of colur that value come from user input?

Comment: cL is a list which contains 6 "valid" colours,  out of which the user can pick any 3 colours, but he can not pick the same colour twice, hence my attempt to amend the list if the user attempts to pick a colour he already picked before, so I can present him with a new, shorter list of "valid" colour options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there.

The method list.remove() modifies the list but does not return the modified list itself.

So if you do the following:

```
cL.remove(colour2)
print(cL)
```

it should give you the desired response.

Comment: Thank you for your solution chumbaloo, was so close indeed yet couldn't figure it out by myself. Very simple resolve, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this:

```
colour2 = str(input("Please re-enter second colour: "))    
cL = [x for x in cL if x != colour2]
```

Comment: That seems like overkill given that there's an in-place remove method, but it'll work.

Comment: I must admit it did take me a while to fully understand what's happening in the suggested code, but I managed to wrap my head around it in the end. Overkill is a good way to describe the code (at least from my beginner's point of view :P ) for the task at hand, but it definitely works just fine so thank you for sharing YOLO!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not just limited to `colour2` but want to do the same for several times, I am providing a more general solution which will work for any number of inputs unless you enter `q`

```
cL = ["red", "green", "blue", "magenta", "orange", "pink"]
deleted = []

while True:
    colour = input("Please enter a colour to delete: (press q to quit)")
    if colour == 'q':
        break
    if colour not in deleted:
        cL.remove(colour)
        deleted.append(colour)
    else:
        print ("%s already deleted. Try entering another color" %colour)
```

---

**Sample Output**

```
Please enter a colour to delete: (press q to quit)red
Please enter a colour to delete: (press q to quit)red
red already deleted. Try entering another color
Please enter a colour to delete: (press q to quit)green
Please enter a colour to delete: (press q to quit)pink
Please enter a colour to delete: (press q to quit)red
red already deleted. Try entering another color
Please enter a colour to delete: (press q to quit)green
green already deleted. Try entering another color
Please enter a colour to delete: (press q to quit)q
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer Bazingaa, I really like the "press q to quit" feature in order to break out of the loop. I will however use a more simple method suggested here by chumbaloo, as I will also be marked on number of lines of code and have to keep the code as short as I can. Cheers, much appreciated!

Comment: Sure. No problem. Glad to provide an alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand you have a list of colors, and you want the user to start picking colors from that list, and if he picks a color that isn't in the list, or a color that he has already picked, it should tell him to pick a different color.

If that's the case this is what it would look like

```
colors_list = ["red", "green", "blue", "magenta", "orange", "pink"]
colors_chosen = []

while colors_list:
    print("Please select a color from this list: {}".format(colors_list))
    color_selected = input()

    while color_selected not in colors_list:
        print("The color selected is not one of the options")
        print("Please select a color from this list: {}".format(colors_list))
        color_selected = input()

    colors_list.remove(color_selected)
    colors_chosen.append(color_selected)

print("These are the colors you chose: {}".format(colors_chosen))
```

So what we're doing is we have a list of all posible colors, and we're using a loop that will be repeating while this list isn't empty (You can replace the while loop with a for loop if you only want the user to chose n colors instead of all of them). Inside that loop we will ask the user for a color, and if it's not a color that's inside the list it will go into a while loop until the user picks a valid color that's inside the list. Once the user does pick a valid color we will remove said color from the list and add it to a list where we'll store the colors the user has chosen. Repeat this process until the list of colors is empty and that's it.

You might want to display different messages if the user typed something that isn't a color (like "car" or something like that), or if he typed a color that he/she had already picked before. To do this you'd need to check if the word typed by the user is not in the list of colors but it is in the list of words chosen then print "You can't pick a word you've already chosen!", and if it's in neither list then print "You have to pick an actual color!".

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Camilo Andres Rosales Marraui. Yes the task at hand is pretty much as you described it, so we're on the same page. Your suggestion is really helpful and will help me slightly improve my code before the final submission, I know I could go crazy on implementing robustness in my code at this stage but because this part of the coursework does not carry so many marks with it, I will have to keep it a bit simpler than what you have suggested. Very much appreciate the explanation which walked me through your code, very helpful!